# How to use Laravel belongsToMany with pivot table and a Boolean column?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to retrieve data using a belongsToMany relationship in Laravel. So I have Student and Course model and they have a many to many relationship, but there are few courses that are compulsory so we don't want to keep those in pivot table, instead we have a Boolean column called compulsory. Now, I want to retrieve all courses for all users including the ones that are compulsory in belongsToMany relation.
Any suggestions ?

```
Student
- id
- name
```

```
Course
- id
- name
- compulsory
```

```
course_student pivot table
- id
- student_id
- course_id
```

Comment: please share table schema, will get some help

Comment: @MiteshRathod I have added the schema, is that helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

That looks quite simple, just use where in your relationship definition. If that doesnt work, please share how are your relationships defined. If you separate compulsory and noncompulsory courses quite often, I would stucture my relationsips as such:

```
 class Student extends Model{

   public function courses(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class);
}

  public function compulsoryCourses(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->courses()->where('compulsory', 1);
}

  public function noncompulsoryCourses(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->courses()->where('compulsory', 0);
}
```

Comment: We cannot use where on a relation because its not gonna get all of the compulsory courses. It will only filter from the courses relation that means compulsory courses are already left out.

Comment: If those are already filtered out at the relationship level, then I would think about restructuring the relationship..

Answer (score 0):

you can apply where conditions while you are calling any relationship inside with the use of the callback function.

```
Student::with['courses' => function ($q) {
   $q->where('compulsory', 1);
}];
```

Comment: Nope that will only filter items that are already fetch using the relationship, it had to be part of pivot table in that case.

Comment: i think you build hasmanythrough relationship, in that case you can use wherehas